# How can i add 2 to only even numers using for/list? Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Using Racket: i have been asked to  "Add 2 to the even numbers of the list?"

i am not sure how to implement this in the correct format,did try a number of diffrent ways,i just it check those if,there,are,any add 2 to that value.

```
    ( define add2-list2
( lambda ( l )
( for/list ([ i (even? l)])  (+ 2 i )
)))
```

Comment: Which exact programming language are you using? (Common) Lisp, Scheme, and Racket are all different things. Please [edit] your question. And please make sure your code uses standard formatting to make it easier for people to read it and help you.

Comment: It helps a lot to become familiar with basic Scheme/Racket functions (eg `append`, `filter`, `map`, `reverse`, etc) and how they are typically put together, before learning Racket specific functions with many options and variants (`for/list` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the new requirements, the `even?` test is in the wrong place, you should use an `if` condition, like this:

```
(define add2-list2
   (lambda (l)
      (for/list ([i l])
        (if (even? i) (+ i 2) i))))
```

For example:

```
(add2-list2 '(1 2 4 5))
=> '(1 4 6 5)
```

Comment: thank you so much,it was just so confusing,say now if i wanted to Add 2 to the even numbers of the list?  how would i apply the function even so it checks "i" so it only updates those even numbers and not just every element in the list

Comment: @user3569752 it's not clear what you want. Please edit the original question with the new requirements, and provide an example, given an input list write how you expect the answer to be. For example, if the input is this: `(3-list2 '(1 2 3 4 5))` what's the output supposed to look like? write the expected list.

Comment: e,g  based on the input '( 1 2 4 5) it should output '(1 4 6 5)